# Como guardar ficheiros na cache do browser

Tags: php, html

Experimentei uma ferramenta da google para testar a velocidade do meu site. 
http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Foi-me mostrado vários pontos que são necessários corrigir, como por exemplo, "Tirar partido da colocação em cache do navegador". Pelo o que entendi é guardar ficheiros na cache do browser evitando serem sempre carregados quando entro na página. Como posso fazer isto?

Como linguagem de programação estou a usar o php.

Nota: todos as sugestões para melhorar o site que me apareceram estão na imagem seguinte: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para tirar partido da cache do navegador, essencialmente precisamos dar a conhecer ao navegador quando é que os ficheiros que ele acabou de recolher expiram, para que até essa data ele os mantenha e não vá recolher novos.

Esta informação pode ser passada do servidor para o navegador de algumas maneiras. Em baixo exemplo com recurso ao ficheiro `.htaccess` do Apache, exemplo com recurso à função `header()` do PHP e exemplo com uso de `META` tag em HTML:

## Apache

Criando um ficheiro com o nome `.htaccess` na raiz do nosso projeto ou numa pasta e/ou sub-pasta onde temos determinados elementos que pretendemos controlar, conseguimos definir o prazo de validade dos ficheiros enviados para o navegador fazendo uso do módulo [`mod_expires`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

#### Exemplo

```
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType image/pjpeg "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "modification plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 3 months"
```

No exemplo em cima estamos a indicar por cada tipo de ficheiro qual a sua validade, ou seja, por quanto tempo deverá o navegador guardar os mesmos em cache.

- `access plus 3 months` → A partir do acesso ao ficheiro, guardar por 3 meses
- `modification plus 3 months` → A partir da data de modificação, guardar por 3 meses

## PHP

Via PHP podemos fazer uso da função [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) para dar a conhecer ao navegador a partir de quando deverá considerar o ficheiro como expirado:

```php
// A partir das 5h da manhã do dia 20-07-2020 o navegador deve puxar nova cópia
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2020 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Ou podemos também:

```php
// Ficheiro expira em 30 dias (60sec * 60min * 24horas * 30dias)
header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");
```

Tudo o que seja enviado para o navegador através do PHP deve ter cabeçalhos adequados para controlo de cache de forma a otimizar o tempo de download da página quando falamos de conteúdos que mudam muito esporadicamente.

## HTML

Com HTML também podemos definir uma meta tag para indicar ao navegador quando é que a página expira, [ver especificações aqui](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```html
 <!-- Não fazer cache -->
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Os valores aceites são:

- Public - pode ser armazenado em cache público
- Private - só pode ser armazenado em cache privado
- no-Cache - não podem ser armazenado em cache
- no-Store - pode ser armazenado em cache, mas não pode ser arquivado

---

## Sumário

Cache via Apache é útil para controlar quando expiram documentos tipo imagens, PDF, CSS, JS, etc...

Cache via PHP e HTML é particularmente útil para controlar quando expira uma página cujo conteúdo é estático por determinado tempo, dinâmico mas só alterado de X em X tempo ou definir conteúdo que nunca deve ficar em cache.

Claro que isto também pode ser realizado via Apache como explicado em cima.

**Nota:** Esta resposta visa dar uma luz sobre o controlo de cache e algumas formas ao nosso dispor. Existem demasiados assuntos e técnicas sobre o controlo de cache que podem ser utilizadas para objetivos específicos, mas ficou aqui uma introdução.

Comment: De salientar que não é possível controlar a cache que ficheiros externos (ex. https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode setar a diretiva [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) através da função [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) diretamente nos arquivos em PHP.

Você também pode controlar o cacheamento dos arquivos diretamente nas configurações do servidor (ex.: [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html)).

Comment: Tente colocar exemplos, respostas apenas com links se tornam inúteis se os links quebrarem.